# How to fix routes in angular

Tags: angular

Getting below error while using angular and md bootstrap.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'About'
>
> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'About'
>       at enter code

**HTML**

```
<li class="nav-item"> 
    <a class="nav-link waves-light" routerLink='/About' mdbWavesEffect>About US</a> 
</li>
```

**MODULE TS**

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; 

const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent , pathMatch: 'prefix'}, 
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent , pathMatch: 'prefix'}, 
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent , pathMatch: 'prefix'} 
]; 

imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes , { enableTracing: true }), ]
```

Comment: at 

 <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link waves-light" routerLink='/About' mdbWavesEffect>About US</a>
      </li>

app.module.ts:

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
 
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent , pathMatch: 'prefix'},
  { path: 'about',  component: AboutComponent , pathMatch: 'prefix'},
  { path: 'contact',  component: ContactComponent , pathMatch: 'prefix'}
];

  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes , { enableTracing: true }),
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off your html should look like this

```
<a class="nav-link waves-light" [routerLink]="['/about']" mdbWavesEffect>About Us</a>
```

notice also how `/about` is spelt with a lower case `a` and not a capital like in your example

routes are case sensitive! this should fix your problem

For more information on angular routing you can go [here](https://angular.io/start/routing)

Comment: Thanks ..it worked... i tried the same syntax but only thing is removed the case sensitive which i did not tried.. now it is working fine.. thank you

Comment: One more question please...getting below error..

ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

Comment: @KoushikSuripeddi you will have to post a new question and format it correctly, not through comments

Comment: Case sensitive correction is enough. You don't need to add uneccessary brackets here : you transform the left side of the expression so it'll await a javascript value and you transform the right side of the expression to be a string interpreted as a javascript expression. Just a waste.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon There not mandatory, but its a good habit to get into using them, since they are required for more complex router navigation